# Conditional Load JS - if pre tag in content

Tags: javascript, css

I have CMS that uses code-prettify for syntax highlighting

Only 10% of the pages have code and use pre tags

```
<pre class="prettyprint">
```

for syntax highlight.

But prettify.js is loaded on all the pages and adds to load time

Is is possible to conditionally load prettify.js based on presence of pre tag in the code?

Comment: Yes, easy. Check if there are class prettyprint, load script by appending script tag Manually initialize prettyprint.

Answer (score 0):

This code will do the work. Checks if the pre element is in range. If so then adds the script to the head.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            if($('pre').length){
                $('head').append('<script src="pretify.js></script>');
            });
        });
```

If you want to do that based on class rather than the html element then you will have to use .classname rather than the element name itself.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
                if($('.prettyclass').length){
                    $('head').append('<script src="pretify.js></script>');
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick if you add it below all `<pre>` tags and replace the `<path>` wildcard with the real address.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (document.querySelectorAll("pre.prettyprint").length > 0) {
        var script = document.createElement("script");

        script.src = "<path>/prettify.js";

        document.head.appendChild(script);
    }
</script>
```